openapi-generator python - how to convert DynamicSchema objects to proper model
with openapi-generator python >= 7.0 version, all API response are de-serialized as 'DynamicSchema' classes. Is there a way to convert to model (that are generated correctly) without the need of handling DynamicSchema class?
Thanks
